# Why is my output different than expected when I print a URL?

Tags: perl

I have the following code to print a URL:

```
$active_url="-http://xxxx.vim.tlt.xxxxx.it/ddts/ddts_main?bug_id=$parent&REMOTE_USER=nni&LastForm=DumpBug";
print "active_url=$active_url";
```

I get the value of `$parent` from a database. However, when I run the code, the output isn't what I expect:

```
$active_url= &REMOTE_USER=nni&LastForm=DumpBugdts/ddts_main?bug_id=ONDvx42368
```

When I print `$parent` using Data::Dumper, I get:

```
';AR1 = 'ONDvx42368
```

although I would expect it to print something like:

```
$VAR1 = 'ONDvx42368'
```

What could cause this issue? For reference, here is my complete program and its output:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::Pg;
use Data::Dumper;

#print Dumper $relations;
my @remove;
my @temp_value;
my $relation_id=$dbh->selectrow_array("select id from customfield where cfname='Relations'");
my $ddts_id=$dbh->selectrow_array("select id from customfield where cfname='DDTS_Identifier'");
my $src_issue='PROJ-83294';

if (exists $relations->{$src_issue}->{'ddts_identifier'}) {
    my @temp_value;
    my $rel=$dbh->selectrow_array("XXXXX");

    if($rel ne '') { # rel= PARENT-ONDvx42368\n CHILD-TSDnm47353
        my @rel=split/\n/,$rel;

        foreach my $relation(@rel) {
            my @link=split/[- ]/,$relation; #$relation= PARENT-ONDvx42698
            my $link_type=@link[0];

            for(my $i=1;$i<=$#link;$i++) {
                my $active_url="$link_type-@link[1]-http://tljnu.vim.tlt.alcatel.it/ddts/ddts_main?bug_id=".@link[1]."&REMOTE_USER=nm_ni&LastForm=DumpBug");
                print "active_url=$active_url";

                push(@temp_value,$active_url);
                $relation=~ s/@link[$i]//;
            }

            if ($relation =~ m/[0-9]/){
                push(@temp_value,$relation);
            }
        }

        my $new_value=join("\n",@temp_value);
        print "updated=$new_value\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
&REMOTE_USER=nm_ni&LastForm=DumpBugdts/ddts_main?bug_id=ONDvx42368
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, your code outputs `active_url=-http://xxxx.vim.tlt.xxxxx.it/ddts/ddts_main?bug_id=ONDvx42368&REMOTE_USER=nni&LastForm=DumpBug`. Are you really using the above code? Or are you initializing `$parent` by some other means, e.g. reading from a file?

Comment: what is the DASH in front of http? also please share little bit more of the code so that we can see other values

Comment: I'm reading parent value from database. If I print $parent value I'm getting correct output. Is '-' escape character?

Comment: You `print "active_url=..."` and you say your output is `$active_url=...` (note the addition of `$`). Either 1) the code you posted is not your real code or 2) the output you posted is not your real output. Copy and paste the *exact* code and output; do not try to type it in by hand since you're sure to make mistakes.

Comment: After your edit, it's clear that you misrepresented your code. Initially, you said you had `$active_url="-http://...`; in your complete program you have `my $active_url="$link_type-@link[1]-http://`. Since it's unclear what your code and output *really* look like, and what you describe is not reproducible, I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a newline at the end of your `$parent` value.

If I add a newline I get this

```
$parent = "ONDvx42368\n";
$active_url = "-http://xxxx.vim.tlt.xxxxx.it/ddts/ddts_main?bug_id=$parent&REMOTE_USER=nni&LastForm=DumpBug";
print "active_url=$active_url";
```

**output**

```
active_url=-http://xxxx.vim.tlt.xxxxx.it/ddts/ddts_main?bug_id=ONDvx42368
&REMOTE_USER=nni&LastForm=DumpBug
```

I suggest that you confirm the contents of `$parent` by writing

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $parent;
```

which, in my case, outputs

```
$VAR1 = "ONDvx42368\n";
```

so that the newline becomes visible.

Comment: But if I print variable $parent, it is giving output in different way.`print Dumper $parent; OUTPUT ';AR1 = 'ONDvx42368`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to

```
$parent="ONDvx42368";
print qq(active_url=-http://xxxx.vim.tlt.xxxxx.it/ddts/ddts_main?bug_id=$parent&REMOTE_USER=nni&LastForm=DumpBug
);
```

Comment: Tried not working......                             if I print $parent  variable using Dumper it is printing like ';AR1 = 'ONDvx42368 instead of (VAR1 = 'ONDvx42368'). please help me